# Output file of the C Preprocessor

Tags: c, output, c-preprocessor

Theoretical question:
What exactly is the language-format of the C Preprocessor. I know what it does, what it is used for, when it gets called but i cannot find ANYWHERE if its output is: a) assembly code, b)C source code(it is said that it can look like it) or c)machine language (I don't think this is it, but a guess).

Comment: The C preprocessor does text replacements only. The output corresponds to the input, i.e the preprocessor macros and the other text in the input file.

Comment: input: C source code; output C source code with comments removed (replaced with a space) and "a few" other tweaks

Comment: Have you checked its output? That clears up a lot. Like on Linux you can do gcc -E some-file.c .

Comment: Or on Windows Mingw `gcc -E main.c > pp.c` then `gcc pp.c -osomething.exe`.

Comment: @Bodo: The C preprocessor substitutes preprocessor tokens, not text, and it also has features for concatenating, stringifying, conditional and unconditional inclusion, reporting errors, controlling the floating-point environment and complex arithmetic, and compiler expansions to C.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Of course you are right. My remark was simplified, it is more complicated. My main point, which apparently I failed to make clear, is that the output language corresponds the input language. If the input is C code, the output will be C code. If the input is something else, the output will be something else. For example try an input file with these lines: `#define FOO Hello World!` `#define BAR(bar) bar bar` `BAR(FOO)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When preprocessing is integrated into a C compiler, its output within the compiler may be in the form of preprocessor tokens and white-space sequences, both of which are effectively sequences of characters arranged into groups, represented internally in any way the compiler designers choose. (For example, the tokens for input text `int main(void)` would be `int`,  , `main`, `(`, `void`, and `)`.)

When preprocessor output is written to a file, it is text with white-space characters as needed to separate tokens. This output is source code ready to be compiled with no further preprocessing; you can give it to a C compiler just as you would ordinary C source code. However, it may include additional non-standard text to support compiler features, such as `#` lines that contain information about the original source file names and line numbers.

Answer (score 1):

> Theoretical question: What exactly is the language-format of the C Preprocessor. I know what it does, what it is used for, when it gets called but i cannot find ANYWHERE if its output is: a) assembly code, b)C source code(it is said that it can look like it) or c)machine language (I don't think this is it, but a guess).

Well, it is a **Pre-processor** associated with the C compiler... ANYWHERE are probably a bit too much places to search: it must be documented for each compiler in the, well, compiler options, so it must be the one place to search

The preprocessor is not a compiler and all the preprocessor knows is text. It receives text, output text, intercepts things that starts with `#` and does its thing. Like `nroff` does.

**So there is no language format for the preprocessor output: it is just text**

### EXAMPLE using gcc 10.2 on Windows

A search for `gcc preprocessor output option` gets this in the first page

[image: Searching for " gcc preprocessor output option "]

Anyway quoting from [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html)

> If you use the -E option, nothing is done except preprocessing. Some of these options make sense only together with -E because they cause the preprocessor output to be unsuitable for actual compilation.

#### file pp1.h

```
// pp1.h
    int x = 300;
// end of pp1.h
```

#### file pp2.h

```
// pp2.h
    return 
// end of pp2.h
```

#### file pp.c

```
#include "pp1.h"

int main(void)
{
                #include "pp2.h" 
    x;
}
// end of pp.c
```

#### Output of `gcc -E pp.c`

```
# 1 "pp.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "pp.c"
# 1 "pp1.h" 1

    int x = 300;
# 2 "pp.c" 2

int main(void)
{
# 1 "pp2.h" 1

    return
# 6 "pp.c" 2
    x;
}
```

Due to -E option the code is not compiled, but it is valid C for sure because it is what we do all the time: use some `#define`, some `#include` and compile our code.
We can pipe this to gcc again and generate the program as usual using just

```
    gcc -E pp.c | gcc -o pp.exe -xc -
```

And run the program as usual:

```
C:\src>pp

C:\src>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
300
```

### Using the preprocessor with generic text

Sure, it is a poor use, but just as a 5min illustration of the case, here t1.txt is a list of cities:

#### t1.txt

```
#include "t1.h"

Microsoft Corporate Offices Addresses(where found)

Austin
Costa Mesa
Houston 
Nashville
Memphis
Mountain View
```

#### t1.h

The header has a list of cities and addresses

```
#define    Nashville \
    Nashville: Corporate Sales Office \
    8 City Boulevard, Suite 403 \
    Nashville, TN, USA \
    37209

#define     Memphis \
    Memphis: Corporate Sales Office \
    6465 N. Quail Hollow Road, Suite 200 \
    Memphis, TN, USA \
    38120

#define     Houston \
    Houston: Corporate Sales Office \
    750 Town and Country Boulevard, St. 1000 \
    Houston, TX, USA \
    77024
// end of t1.h
```

#### preprocessor output

This command

```
gcc -E -x c t1.txt | grep -v "^#"
```

shows under gcc 10.2

```
Microsoft Corporate Offices Addresses(where found)

Austin
Costa Mesa
Houston: Corporate Sales Office 750 Town and Country Boulevard, St. 1000 Houston, TX, USA 77024
Nashville: Corporate Sales Office 8 City Boulevard, Suite 403 Nashville, TN, USA 37209
Memphis: Corporate Sales Office 6465 N. Quail Hollow Road, Suite 200 Memphis, TN, USA 38120
Mountain View
```

Outputs the obvious: appends the office address to the city when found in the list.

Just a toy. Preprocessors does not know programming languages.

Comment: Re “So there is no language format for the preprocessor output: it is just text“: There is a language format for the preprocessor. It is specified in C 2018 6.10 1, with references to grammatical tokens defined in 6.4 1, 6.4.2.1 1, and 6.6 1, the latter of which ties into a good chunk of the C grammar for expressions. As examples that it is not unstructured text, preprocessor errors will be caused by malformed tokens, unterminated `#if` directives, and malformed expressions in `#if` statements.

Comment: the ISO is pedantic. You can use the preprocessor to, well,  preprocess even regular non-C text and it will do its job thing anyway... I see no point in downvoting my answer it you spent time doing this. Write a test as I did...

Comment: Nobody has voted down your answer, and you cannot use the preprocessor to preprocess regular non-C text. Some time ago, I wanted to use it on text that included quoted text spanning multiple lines, as is normal in English text, and it could not be used for that due to the issues I stated. That is not pedantic; it is a real-world use case that depended on the specification of preprocessing. This answer needlessly makes false statements.

Comment: One thing is "text that included quoted text spanning multiple lines, as is normal in English text" other thing is text, other thing is C. I said that the C standard is pedantic in this case. Quoting again you: "real-world use case that depended on the specification of preprocessing" is valid for every preprocessor... I will insert an useless example in my answer that goes the other way, @EricPostpischil

Comment: "needlessly makes false statements" sounds a bit rude about my post, @EricPostpischil

Comment: It is factual. The statement “So there is no language format for the preprocessor output: it is just text” is false, and there is no need for it. Often there may be some benefit in simplifying an answer because a student does not have the foundation needed for a full explanation, but this can usually be done with statements that are correct but leave parts to be explained at other times. There is no need to make false statements that preprocessing just text. Instead of trying to defend false statements, you could improve them.

Comment: "There is no need to make false statements that preprocessing just text:" Really? It is funny to call something fact or truth based on your opinion only, but it is for sure possible. Use maybe `gcc -E` with anything and when you got output that is not just text post here for us to see. Note that I updated my answer with an example of the "not-text" output: an address list

Comment: The point of comments is to improve questions and answers.  @EricPostpischil is correct here, both technically and practically; the CPP is a language (a strange non-Turing complete language, but a language nonetheless).  There are restrictions to the input in the form of acceptable tokens and various constructs (directives, expressions, etc).  These are not opinions; they are correct descriptions of the specifications that define the C preprocessor.

Comment: @HWalters as you may already know, or see in the code I showed: although the preprocessor is tied to the compiler it can be used for anything, like some sort of mail merge as I showed above. And when using -E option the output of the preprocessor does not even go to the C++ or C or Spanish compiler: goes to stdout. It makes no difference if the language is non-Turing complete or even a language in itself.

Comment: You're just lucky Microsoft doesn't have a corporate office in Martha's Vineyard.  There is a grammar, and there is text that is not accepted.  It's easy to find cases of text that isn't accepted... just look at the grammar.

Comment: [From gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html)  "If you use the -E option, nothing is done except preprocessing. Some of these options make sense only together with -E because they cause the preprocessor output to be unsuitable for actual compilation", There is text that IS accepted, @HWalters, and one can used this at will. The grammar to look at is the particular preprocessor one, only. The compiler does not have a clue. May be you could do as I did and provide some code or text, "improving questions and answers"

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/YWoEPe <- error on line 25; ignored by gcc's implementation which is just that... an implementation... not a specification of the C preprocessor.  Line 32 shows how we can use the C preprocessor for markup... how exciting!  Line 33 shows it failing on your implementation because the C preprocessor has a grammar.

Comment: it is funny that you seem to be serious about this at the point of using the same gcc 10.2 on compiler explorer(!) to compile a text that is not intended to be compiled, as per the documentation you can see on gcc docs itself. Hint: I provided you a link above. Using gcc -E the compiler will not be invoked at all. Ask Matt Godbolt to write maybe a PreProcessor Explorer... or just look at stdout on you terminal.

Comment: Godbolt compiler explorer lets you pass flags to the compiler, such as the `-E -P` I'm invoking it with in that link.  Methinks you should look a bit closer.

Comment: FYI, the problem with line 25 is UB; try looking [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) instead of the gcc documentation; reference especially 6.4p3 "If a ' or " character matches the last category, the behavior is undefined."; x-ref 6.4, 6.4.4.4.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228685/discussion-between-h-walters-and-arfneto).